# PostgreSQL: Command line messages in Chinese Language (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, postgresql, command-line, psql

In SQL Shell (psql), when I write commands for example `\du`. The results I am getting are in the Chinese language. Even `postgresql.conf` file is showing that the language is English as you can see down below:

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'English_United States.936'           # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.936'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.936'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'English_United States.936'               # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

I even installed the old version (11.8) but it was a vain attempt.
[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOJcb.png) of the results that the command line is showing. Thank you.

Comment: Try `SET LC_MESSAGES=English` on the command line before you start `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It worked. Thank you so much. But it is not working for SQL Shell terminal. When I open SQL Shell, it starts querying `Server`, `Database`, `Port`, etc, and enters into the `postgres=#` immediately. Thus it is not letting me enter this command `SET LC_MESSAGES=English`.

Comment: I don't know what that "SQL Shell" is. If that is a batch file, then edit that batch file. Or simply set `LC_MESSAGES` as [an environment variable](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. SQL Shell is a batch file that came with the PostgreSQL software. I edited that file and added `SET LC_MESSAGES=English` and it also worked fine.